# Docker Compose: Volumes not working on Windows Nano

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nano-server

I've got two Windows Nano docker containers ... one with a service on, the second with my Automated Acceptance Tests.

I'm trying to add a volume to the aat container so I can copy off the tests output.

I've seen elsewhere I'm supposed to use ...

- COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1

But can't seem to get anywhere :S

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  fancyservice:
    restart: always
    image: fancyservice
  aat-runner:
    environment:
      - FancyServiceUrl=http://fancyservice/
      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
    volumes:
      - .:/output:rw
    restart: always
    image: aat-runner
```

I get:

```
ERROR: for aat_aat-runner_1  Cannot create container for service aat-runner: invalid volume spec "/output"

ERROR: for aat-runner  Cannot create container for service aat-runner: invalid volume spec "/output": invalid volume specification: '\output'
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Comment: If it's an environment variable for the cli itself, shouldn't it be set in Windows? Maybe in the command prompt before calling `docker-compose`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the volume at the same level as "services:" as well as against the individual container ...

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  fancyservice:
    restart: always
    image: fancyservice
  aat-runner:
    environment:
      - FancyServiceUrl=http://fancyservice/
      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
    volumes:
      - .:/output:rw
    restart: always
    image: aat-runner
    volumes:
      - aat-output:c:\aat-output\

volumes:
  aat-output:
```